# How to handle task that is repeated through a month with camunda

Tags: bpmn, camunda, bpmn.io

I'm new to Camunda and didn't find any tutorial or reference explaining how to achieve the following:

This is a workflow to monthly hour registry. So an employee should compile a "form" task to insert how many hours he has worked every day in the month and save it on a sheet for example. At the end of the month the account take the sheet with the hours and make a kind of report for each employee.

Is it possible to handle this kind of recursion (do a task once a day into the month) with camunda and any idea how to make it with a bpmn graph?

Comment: have a look at https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/reference/bpmn20/events/timer-events/

Comment: I see. It's good, so do you think i should split the workflow in 2 pool, one for the employee and one for the account. The employee complete the task every 24h and the account take the hour first day of the month?